# After update AdSense API version 2, no data from reports

Tags: version, adsense, adsense-api

I tried like below

```
https://adsense.googleapis.com/v2/accounts/pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/reports:generate?dateRange=CUSTOM&startDate.year=2021&startDate.month=10&startDate.day=12&endDate.year=2021&endDate.month=10&endDate.day=12&currencyCode=USD&metrics=AD_REQUESTS&dimensions=AD_CLIENT_ID&alt=json
```

I didn't get any error code, http status was 200. But I can't see any rows data. Only thing I can see is header information.

I checked all release note about v2 because something might be depreciated. But metrics(AD_REQUESTS) requested is okay and dimensions(AD_CLIENT_ID) requested is also okay.

What did I miss?

Comment: Is the same user accessing v2 and v1.4? I would suggest fetching all the AdClients with this user to make sure it has access to your AdSense data.

Comment: Yes, same user. It's work if I test v1.4. But if I change the version v2, then it doesn't work. All thing is same, but only change, v1.4 -> v2.